# too many arguments error after updating drush to latest dev

Tags: drush

I am getting the following error when I try to run any command in drush.

Error in argument 1, char 2: option not found r
/home6/whereisa/.composer/vendor/bin/drush: line 124: [: too many arguments

This started happening after i upgraded to the latest drush (7.x.dev).  all 6.x versions of drush work fine
I am running php 5.4 on bluehost shared web hosting.

Please advise

Regards,
Ash

Comment: Can you provide an example of a command that gives you this error

Comment: @Sisyphus , drush cc all is an example of a command that will throw this error.  the command still executes with a successful outcome, but the error shows first.  Every command I run gives me this error.

Comment: Did you try including an alias ?